# How to inject constructor parameter deep in the dependcies at runtime while resolving through unity

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library, unity-interception

In the below if I am trying to inject a constructor parameter in one of the dependencies of the model at runtime, it doesn't take with Parameter Override option. Is there any thing else that we need to do?

```
    public class Test: ITest
    {
        ITestChild _testChild ;
        public Test(ITestChild testChild)
        {
            _testChild = testChild;
        }
    }

    public class TestChild: ITestChild
    {
        ITestChildChild _testChildChild ;
        public Test(ITestChildChild testChildChild)
        {
            _testChildChild = testChildChild;
        }
    }

    public class TestChildChild: ITestChildChild
    {
        public TestChildChild()
        {
        }
    }
```

Mapping Unity:

```
    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITest, Test>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestChild TestChild>();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestChildChild, TestChildChild>();

    Main()
    {
        var testChildChild = new TestChildChild();
        var testObject = UnityContainer.Resolve<ITest>(new ParameterOverride("testChildChild", testChildChild));
    }
```

Comment: There is not error the testChildChild which i am trying to inject using override is not going into  the chain.

Comment: Solution is to use "DependencyOverride"

Answer (score 0):

```
Main()
{
    var testChildChild = new TestChildChild();
    var testObject = UnityContainer.Resolve<ITest>(new DependencyOverride("testChildChild", testChildChild));
}
```